# PHPMailer Connection Timeout (non-gmail)

Tags: email, wordpress, phpmailer

I've been trying to solve this problem for a few days now, but no success so far. I've seen a lot of questions regarding the same problem, but most of them are related to a gmail.com account.

I'm trying to use it with another SMTP through a WP Plugin on my website (WP-Mail-SMTP), but I keep getting Connection Timeout. I've tried to search if my smtp provider (EuroDNS) conflicts with PHPMailer but it resulted 0 answers on google.

I've already tried changing ports (465, 587, 25) and changing encryptions methods (SSL, TLS) but I keep getting the same result.

Is there anyway I can solve this issue?

Comment: It's likely that your ISP is blocking all outbound email connections and wants you to use their own mail server. Read their docs or open a support ticket with them.

Comment: @Synchro Hmm, I'll take a look at that. Thanks.